# pointer behaviors in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

So I've got a code here:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void){
int *p;
int i = 30;
*p = i;
*p = 100;
cout << i << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Could someone point out what's wrong with this code?

I don't think you need to do things like

```
int *p = new int;
```

because it's ok to point to a stack variable.

Current update: I should've figured out this basic common sense stuff long ago...
fix:

```
int *p;
int i = 30;
p = &i;     //this stores the address of i. Then we can reach the value of i by calling *p
```

Comment: But but `p` isn't pointing to anything then!

Comment: There are really too many such questions under c++ tag. Please read textbook and search before asking.

Comment: You need to take the **address** of `i`  and assign it to `p` like so `p = &i`

Comment: Turn your compiler's warnings on and read them!  Your compiler is very capable of telling you what's wrong in this code.

Comment: *In my opinion* -- The address-of operator is discussed in any good C++ book.  Don't code based on your opinion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This dereferences an uninitialized pointer, resulting in UB:

```
*p = i;
```

You probably want this instead:

```
p = &i;
```

Answer (score 3):

The program invokes undefined behavior because `p` is uninitialized. If it were initialized with:

```
int* p = new int;
// the rest of the code
delete p;
```

the `i` would still be the same no matter how you deference the pointer. The pointer does not modify the value of `i` in any way. This:

```
*p = i;
```

does not mean "from now on, whatever I do to `*p` will be reflected to the value of `i`." It simply means assign the value of `i` to a value pointed to by `p`.

You would need to initialize `p` with a reference to `x` using the [address-of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_address-of_operator) operator `&`:

```
int* p = &i;
```

Now `p` *references* `i`. Now you have two names for the same object, one is `*p` and the other is `i`. They both mean the same thing and modify the same object. Changes made to one of them are *reflected* to the other one.

Answer (score 0):

Your question was what's wrong with this code

```
int *p;
int i = 30;
*p = i;
*p = 100;
cout << i << endl;
```

in here `*p=i` you are trying to assign the value of `i` to `*p` but pointer variable can store the address of the variable rather than variable value that you are doing. So, there are two methods to solve this. One is allocate memory using `new` operator and the other is assign address of `i` to `p` `p=&i`